# Efficient Algorithm for finding a large sum-free subset.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, expected-value, probabilistic-method

Erdos's famous result shows that given n nonzero integers, there is a sum-free subset of size> n/3. The traditional proof gives only a pseudopolynomial time algorithm. Alon-Spencer claims that there is a deterministic efficient algorithm using a prime p that is relatively prime to all the given integers. Can one show how?

Comment: I could show a prime exists of size poly(n) which is relatively prime to all n integers.  However, I could not show the prime to be of form 3k+2.

Comment: A set B is sum-free if the a+b=c has no solution with a,b,c\in B.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

The algorithm has been shown to be polynomial: https://doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(94)90063-9

Also in Jukna's combinatorics book: [http://lovelace.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/EC_Book/sample/316-317.pdf](http://lovelace.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/%7Ejukna/EC_Book/sample/316-317.pdf)